# Looping through a hierarchy tree and creating a REACT UI off of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hierarchy

So I have a project I am trying to complete where I am given a hierarchy tree.
From the tree I need to loop through the data and create a tree in the UI so the user can navigate through their hierarchy tree.

Here is an example:

```
`const tree = [
  {
    name: "Root Node",
    nodes: [
      {
        name: "Node 1",
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "Sub node"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Node 2",
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "Sub node "
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Node 3",
        nodes: [
          {
            name: "Sub node"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];`
```

Now this hierarchy could have any number of nodes and any number of child nodes.  So the code should be recursive so that it will work for any amount of nodes.

So I have tried a few things to try and loop through the nodes and get them all but I am struggling to then apply the retrieved data to the UI.

My first attempt was to create a function, that loops through all the top level nodes.  For each top level node, loop through its child nodes and get the names, then if that child node has its own sub nodes then recursively call this same function to get those nodes.  But the issue I am having is how to store each nodes name and in a way that when I go to render it to my react view each node is under the correct parent.

```
`function getTree(node){
    let nodeName = node.name;
    let children = getChildren(node);
    // now I have the parent (nodeName) and its children ? 

}`

`function getChildren(node){
  let children = []; // store the data in here somehow?
  if(node.nodes){  //if this node has its own child nodes
  for (var j = 0; j < node.nodes.length; j++) {
    if (node.nodes[j].nodes){
      getChildren(org.nodes[j].nodes);
    }
  }
  }
}`
```

I feel like im on the right lines but it still doesn't feel right or work.  In the react render method I am then mapping over the tree const above and passing each tree node into the getTree function.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayUIparser =(arr)=>{
const res =[];
let {name,nodes} =arr[0];
if(!nodes){
res.push(<li>{name}</li>)
}else {
res.push(nodes.map((item)=>{
return <ul>{item.name}<li> {this.arrayUIparser(item.nodes)} </li></ul>}))
        }             
return <ul >{res}</ul>;    
  }
```

If I understand you right it can be something like that.